# Edit shipping description in "checkout onepage review"

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, shipping

I want to edit the shipping label in my review order (last step before user confirm the order)

I want in

```
frontend/theme/mytheme/template/checkout/onepage/review.phtml
```

and in the files in

```
frontend/theme/mytheme/template/checkout/onepage/review/
```

but I dont know where i can edit this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've found the phtml that prints this text

This is the origin file:

> app/design/base/default/template/tax/checkout/shipping.phtml

I've copied this file in to my theme like this:

> app/design/theme/mytheme/template/tax/checkout/shipping.phtml

Now we can edit this lines:

```
<td style="<?php echo $this->getStyle() ?>" class="a-right" colspan="<?php echo $this->getColspan(); ?>">
    <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getTotal()->getTitle()) ?>
</td>
```

And write what we want:

```
<td style="<?php echo $this->getStyle() ?>" class="a-right" colspan="<?php echo $this->getColspan(); ?>">
    ***** MY CUSTOM TEXT HERE *****
</td>
```

Hope this helps someone